# How to use VSCode to watch a Chinese string in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, unicode, watch

I want to debug a C++ program in VS code. However, when I watch a variable which is a Chinese string, it displays a series of Unicode characters. How can I get the correct Chinese value of this variable?
[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that those aren't Unicode escapes. The CJK Unicode blocks are all above 0x3400.

Comment: This might be related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/31442.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the system charset in docker. The default charset en_US.UTF-8 doesn't support Chinese. When I set the charset to C.utf8, now the VS Code can display Chinese string correctly.

```
LANG=C.utf-8
source /etc/profile
```

[image]